# Non-finitely generated ring of regular functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is remarked in Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry 1 that Rees and Nagata constructed examples of quasiprojective varieties such that the ring of regular functions is not finitely generated, but I cannot find the source he is referring to. Can anyone give such examples here? Does that mean we can't really say anything about the ring of regular functions of a quasi-projective variety?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a theorem that a quasi-projective variety is affine if and only if it is Stein (we're working over C, say) and its ring of functions is finitely generated.  So find a Stein manifold that isn't affine, and that will do it.

And, after a bit of looking, it appears that Vakil may have rediscovered the Rees and Nagata example, [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/files/nonfg.pdf).

Comment: I don't think that a Stein manifold that isn't affine will do the trick. For instance, if we take Serre's example (  P^1 bundle over an elliptic curve obtained as the projectivization of the unique non-trivial extension 0-> O -> V -> O -> 0 minus the section determined by O -> V)  is Stein, and every regular function on it is constant since the section has zero self-intersection.

Comment: I was certain that I'd read that Stein + f.g. => Affine for varieties, but that seems like a counterexample.  I must be missing a hypothesis.  Asking a question to try to find out exactly what is true.  Must be some nontriviality hypothesis for the ring of regular functions, I'm guessing (maybe separates points?)

Comment: Ok, so according to Tony Pantev on my related question, what we need is a quasi-affine variety that is Stein.  Then we have affine if and only if finitely generated.  So it's a matter of looking for non-affine Stein manifolds which are quasi-affine.